# SiteMapProvider for Managed Navigation

Tags: managed-navigation, portalsitemapprovider

Maybe Ive got this wrong, but I was hoping to have a Custom SiteMapProvider(SMP) for my Global Managed Navigation top menu.

I have a managed navigation that reads from my metadataservice and works well. But when I activate the feature that contains my custom (derived from PortalSiteMapProvider), the
managed top menu disappears and I have only the "standard menu" that displays the subwebs.

If I set a breakpoint in my custom SMP I only get the subwebs node.

Have I misunderstood this? Im thinking that either you have SPs Taxonomy SMP or you have your custom. I was also hoping to derive from Taxonomy SMP, but I cant find example for that.

**So: Is it possible to get the Managed Navigation Nodes and fiddle with the titles, as with a normal SMP?**

(If not I can just put a web control in master page that traverses the menu, i e, without any SMP)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it's sealed I have another idea.

What I've done before is actually just query another SMP in my custom SMP.  This strategy might work for you.  You basically just create a wrapper SMP that queries the taxonomy one and modifies the nodes it returns before you return them in your SMP.  Below is some sample code.

```
public class CustomNavProvider : SiteMapProvider
{
    private const string PROVIDERNAME = "GlobalNavigationTaxonomyProvider";

    public override SiteMapNode RootNode
    {
        get
        {
            return SiteMap.Providers[PROVIDERNAME].RootNode;
        }
    }

    public override SiteMapNode CurrentNode
    {
        get
        {
            return SiteMap.Providers[PROVIDERNAME].CurrentNode;
        }
    }

    public override SiteMapNodeCollection GetChildNodes(SiteMapNode parent)
    {
        SiteMapNodeCollection childNodes = new SiteMapNodeCollection();
        if ((parent == null) || (parent.Key == null)) return childNodes;

        foreach (SiteMapNode tempNode in SiteMap.Providers[PROVIDERNAME].GetChildNodes(parent))
        {
            //do stuff with tempNode
            childNodes.Add(tempNode);
        }

        return childNodes;
    }

    public override SiteMapNode FindSiteMapNode(string rawUrl)
    {
        return SiteMap.Providers[PROVIDERNAME].FindSiteMapNode(rawUrl);
    }

    public override SiteMapNode GetParentNode(SiteMapNode node)
    {
        return SiteMap.Providers[PROVIDERNAME].GetParentNode(node);
    }
}
```

Comment: You might have to play around with which provider to query.  There were a few in the web.config that reference the taxonomy service in addition to the one I put in the code above:  GlobalNavigationSwitchableProvider, CurrentNavigationSwitchableProvider, and CurrentNavigationTaxonomyProvider.

Comment: Hi Steve. Thanks for the new angle. I can get the correct provider, but the title is read only, so even if I get the correct node, I cant change it. I have also tried create new ones, but TaxonomySiteMapNode has no (public) contstructor. (and there goes my initial workaround as well). Im leaning towards collecting the info I need server side, inject it to client and replace labels using js.

Comment: ...actually I was hoping for a "correct"/official way to do this. What I really want to do is show specific language dep on user (from connected term), maybe I should take a step back...

Comment: I'm looking at the code for the taxonomysitemapnode and I am not seeing why the title would be readonly.  Could you create your own sitemapnode and just copy the values over?  SiteMapNode node = new SiteMapNode(this, key, url, title);

Comment: Nevermind, i see in the constructor now where it sets the readonly value.  I am wondering if you could set the readonly property to false and then try setting the title.

Comment: hmm... my mistake, you dont need to return a TaxnomySiteMapNode. As you suggesteed, you could just read from one. However I got into other problem and ended up doing my translations on client side, but Reading data from TaxonomyProvider.... Im marking this as "correct", even though I didnt get all the way, since it answered my question... thanks :)

Comment: It is missing the implementation of the GetRootNodeCore method.

Comment: @SteveLineberry, for some reason I did the same and the method GetChildNodes is never called. Only the CurrentNode and the RootNode methods are called.

Comment: @Tito, it depends on the navigation control which methods get called.

Comment: @SteveLineberry , thanks for your answer, I am having this problems for days already, I described it in here: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/185779/getchildnodes-from-sitemapprovider-is-never-called. 
What do you mean by navigation control ? You mean the SharePoint:AspMenu control in my case ?

Comment: Yea, AspMenu is a navigation control.

Answer (score 0):

Did you take a look at inheriting from:  Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Navigation.TaxonomySiteMapProvider ??

Comment: TaxonomySiteMapProvider is sealed